# Trying to get a fixed background with scrolling text which is using floats and a wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-float, wrapper

I have a webpage where the text, buttons and embed links are all within a wrapper. In addition to this, I am using floats to space them out. However, I am trying add a background which is fixed and remains in place, whilst the webpage is scrolled up and down. I have been unable to do so and from what I have done, the background image either stays at the top of the webpage or bottom of the webpage.

The CSS I have used is this:

```
.Background {
    background-image: url(Background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top;
    position:absolute;
    height:610px;
    width: 700px;
    margin:0;}
```

and for HTML I used:

```
<div><img src="Background.jpg"></div>
```

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS and I am very lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      content here
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the css

```
.content {
  font-size: 55px;
  background: url(http://cdn2-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/30-impossibly-cute-puppies/impossibly-cute-puppy-8.jpg);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Here is a fiddle, if its easier to see - https://jsfiddle.net/d8vzsbL8/

Comment: Brilliant, it works a charm! Thank you a lot for the help.